# PostgreSQL function taking column name as argument

Tags: postgresql, function, arguments, dynamic-sql

I have a table `tab1` with four columns `col1`, `col2`, `col3` and `col4`.

I want to create a function like `f4(a)` where `a` is defined by user and if user types `select f4(col1)` he gets column `tab1.col1`.

Is there any way to create such function in PostgreSQL?

Comment: The question is to broad. You should try something and come back if you have a **specific** problem, not just a requirement dump. Hint: You can query [`pg_attribute`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html) and join [`pg_class`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html) and possibly [`pg_namespace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-namespace.html). And you should think about how to handle the case, when more than one table has a column named like the function's input.

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 2):

There is really not good reason to complicate matters with a function here.
What you should do instead:

```
SELECT col1 FROM tab1;
```

What you ask for:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f4(_col text)
  RETURNS TABLE (col_x text)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 
   format('SELECT %I FROM tab1', _col);
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f4('col1');
```

You need dynamic SQL because SQL does not allow to parameterize identifiers.

Further reading:

- [Using variable for fieldname in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23344722/using-variable-for-fieldname-in-postgresql/23346020#23346020)
- [Define table and column names as arguments in a plpgsql function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384159/define-table-and-column-names-as-arguments-in-a-plpgsql-function/18386034#18386034)